# Entity framework - use same entity twice in same object with one to many fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, one-to-many

Sorry if the title is a bit unclear/ambiguous but I am unsure of how so get the following code bound via Fluent API (if it's even required)

```
public class ChatUser 
{
    [Key]
    public int ChatUserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
    // other properties

    // navigation properties
    public ICollection<ChatMessage> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class ChatMessage
{
    [Key]
    public int ChatMessageId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int UserFromId { get; set; }
    public int UserToId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public ChatUser UserFrom { get; set; }
    public ChatUser UserTo { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I am having is to get the two `"ChatUser"` objects to be bound to the `UserFromId` and `UserToId` - they both come up as `null`.

I need to be able to access a list of "Messages" from a user and when I've got a `Message` object, I need to be able to access both the `UserFrom` and `UserTo` so I can get the properties such as `Name`.

If anyone could point me in the correct direction/any links that I can learn from that would be appreciated.

PS if there is proper terminology for what I am trying to achieve could someone let me know - I was unsure of what to Google to solve my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to your question.

First, for relationships to lazy-load correctly, they need to be marked as `virtual`. This applies to, at least, `UserFrom`, `UserTo` and `Messages`.

Second, it's not possible for a single collection property to load elements from both sides of the relationship. But this is easy to do with a LINQ-to-objets projection:

```
public virtual ICollection<ChatMessage> MessagesFrom { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ChatMessage> MessagesTo { get; set; }

public virtual IEnumerable<ChatMessage> Messages
{
    get { return MessagesFrom.Concat(MessagesTo); }
}
```

You'll need to use the fluent API to map `MessagesFrom` to `UserFrom` and `MessagesTo` to `UserTo`.

That will be something around the lines of `.HasMany(x => MessagesFrom).WithRequired(x => x.UserFrom)`; you can use intellisense and the docs to find out the exact form.

Answer (score -4):

Here is a sample.

```
public class Class1
{
    ChatUser user1 = new ChatUser();

    public Class1()
    {
        //List of Message for current User
        List<ChatMessage> lstChatMessages = user1.Messages.ToList();

        //Take firstMessage in sequence
        ChatMessage firstMessage = lstChatMessages.FirstOrDefault();

        //User from
        ChatUser UserFrom = firstMessage.UserFrom;

        //User To
        ChatUser UserTo = firstMessage.UserTo;

    }
}
```

Start reading some .Net Books

Comment: Don't think there was any need for your subtle dig at me... if you read the question you would know it was the CF issue I was having problems with, not the general .net side of things :)